# Next week, in particular, is my wife(')(,) Liana's(,) show

Tags: punctuation

I was writing an email to my department, and was informing them about an art show my wife was having.  So I wrote:

> Next week, in particular, is my wife Liana's show.

But then I realized that I usually would write "my wife, liana, ...", but the apostrophe made it look strange. Then it occurred to me that maybe I should be putting the apostrophe on "wife" instead.

After thinking about this for more than a few minutes, I decided to drop all commas and send the email, since I was wasting time.  But I wanted to know what the correct punctuation would be in this case.

Also, I apologize if this seems trivial or is a duplicate.  I could not find a decent answer to this elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a possessive noun is followed by an appositive, the 's is added to the appositive, not the noun, and the comma following the appositive is dropped. So you would say, "Next week is my wife, Liana's show."

See [this link](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/possessives.htm) for more information on possessives.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Alex's answer is true.  And it feels to me that the version you chose

*"Next week is my wife Liana's show."*

is idiomatic and also acceptable in American English.