# How should I use a possessive apostrophe when a name is between commas?

Tags: punctuation, commas, possessives, apostrophe, appositives

Is this the correct use of an apostrophe when showing a name and relationship?

> When was your father, Robert's, wedding?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I found some examples of this question being asked before, but I'm not personally convinced yet by any of the answers: [Next week, in particular, is my wife(')(,) Liana's(,) show](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164177), [Appositives with possessiveness?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57700), [Can I place a comma before and after a possessive noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230620)

Comment: Here also is a Wordreference forum thread on this topic: [Double possessives - possessive 's with appositives](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/double-possessives-possessive-s-with-appositives.1379513/)

Comment: Yes, of course; how else could you write it? Btw, there's no need for either of the commas.

Comment: @BillJ, why aren't the commas necessary here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to correctly render it using an appositive and an apostrophe. Instead, if you want to keep representing the possessive with an apostrophe, I'd make "Robert" an [*essential clause*](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/essentialclause.htm) and remove the comma altogether:

> When was your father Robert's wedding?

Comment: No. Logic dictates that there can be no restrictive/defining/essential appositive (it's **not** a clause) here – a person can only have one father. It's an information-adding and non-essential ('When was your father's wedding?' works fine grammatically) appositive. Yes, commas are usually needed round such, but this is a special case where this rule is relaxed. Your version is fine, but the analysis is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Since one can assume there is no ambiguity about 'your' father's name, wouldn't the sentence perhaps sounds better as just:

'When was your father's wedding?'

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: There may be ambiguity in the case of foster or adopted parents - I may have more than one father.