# What is the ’s-possessive form of "the king of Troy, Priam"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, saxon-genitive, appositives

> “This was brought about by **the king of Troy’s, Priam’s,** death.”

In this sentence, should the *’s* be tagged on to “the king of Troy”, “Priam”, or both?

Comment: Here is a similar question, but I think the accepted answer is kind of mediocre: [How should I use a possessive apostrophe when a name is between commas?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368290)

Comment: The _'s_ morpheme began as a noun inflection in Old English, but has clearly now become a [clitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic) which attaches to the end of a whole noun phrase, not to individual words in the phrase.

Comment: As Colin Fine already stated, the whole phrase "the king of Troy Priam" takes the possessive: "the king of Troy Priam's". OTOH, if you prefer better readability, you could it rephrased suitably.

Comment: @DanBron where's the plural noun ending in an "s" in *king of Troy* and *Priam*? I'm asking because you recommended closing this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possessive markers can co-exist side by side if there are two "owners". For example,

> **Agamemnon's wife's** name was Clytemnestra

But in the OP's example saying *…the king of Troy's Priam's death*, without commas, is saying that Priam ‘belongs’ to the King of Troy. That is one too many apostrophes for my liking. Use parenthesis instead of commas to disambiguate the two nouns.

> “This was brought about by **Priam's** (the king of Troy) **death**.”

Alternatively, I would  recommend rephrasing the OP's statement, using a prepositional phrase

> It was brought by the **death of** Priam, the king of Troy.